# Bluetooth app not scanning available devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have made a small app in android studio to scan Bluetooth devices, But the app is not scanning any available device and showing no error. I turn on Bluetooth manually. But when I press Scan Button in the app nothing happens. I want when I press Scan Button a List of available devices should be displayed. I have also added the Bluetooth permissions in manifest file. Java and XML

```js
package com.example.discoverbluetoothobjects;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button scanButton;
    ListView scanListView;
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    BluetoothAdapter myAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        scanListView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.scannedListView);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        });

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver,intentFilter);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringArrayList);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                stringArrayList.add(device.getName());
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/scanButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/scannedListView"
        android:layout_width="301dp"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scanButton" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

codes are attached.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to get the list of all the avaiable Bluetooth devices  and their detail and you will find how to connect to the particular Bluetooth device .. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat